# Caching POST request and GET request on a local machine to get access to content offline

Tags: proxy, cache, local-area-network, local

I'm looking for an existing solution that would allow us to make request normally and let a sort of proxy cache everything we do. 
For instance when querying a REST service the proxy would write the result of the response with related media included. Thus, next time we query it, we get the appropriate response with the local copy of everything the proxy has cached.

The same would apply for POST. When posting, if something goes wrong: let's say the internet is down or service return 500, the POST request and it's content got cached locally and the smart proxy will try to repost the content a certain numbers of time.

I hope it is sufficient clear :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for two different solutions. First is simple proxy server, which cache responses. You can use for example squid for this. Second solution (resending queries after restoring of connection) is quite more complex and I don't know about working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are trying http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/ for GET request which looks fairly simple and efficient. And we are developing our own system for posting. 
Thank you !